# Wordpress contact form 7 plugin submit to a specific page

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I created a custom form using contact form 7 plugin in wordpress. I dont want to send any mail . I just want to submit a form on a specific page and save data into database and third party api called with form data and also 
if any error getting display error on form and if data saved successfully then redirect to success page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code to redirect to success page after submit in "additional setting" of contact form 7

```
on_sent_ok: "location.replace('http://www.example.com/thank-you');"
```

It will redirect to thankyou page after successfully submission.

Also you can use this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/) to store data in database

**EDIT FOR LATEST VERSION**

The method using the `on_sent_ok` hook is no longer recommended so the simplest way is utilizing CF7 custom DOM event to run JavaScript when the wpcf7mailsent event occurs.

**Example Code**

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
  location = 'http://example.com/thank-you';
}, false );
</script>
```

Comment: I want to disable ajax form submittion and form submit on a specific page where php code is handle the post data and call third party software api and send error and success msg on particular page and redirect.

Comment: Define define ('WPCF7_LOAD_JS', false); in your config file if you want to disable ajax

Answer (score 0):

To add a 'redirection' function in the Contact Forms 7 you can just use the free plug-in: [Redirection for Contact Form 7 by Qube One](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wpcf7-redirect/)

And to save the data from the forms, you can just use the free plug-in: [Contact Form CFDB7 by Arshid](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-cfdb7/)

Comment: Some links in your text to those plugins would be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include links.